# Message: Attribute "xmlns:android" was already specified for element "LinearLayout"

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

After trying many solution on web I didn't find solution to this problem.

```
 > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
 Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 > A failure occurred while executing 
  com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
 > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

  ParseError at [row,col]:[13,192]
  Message: Attribute "xmlns:android" was already specified for element "LinearLayout".
```

My xml Linearlayout is not having "xmlns:android" attributes. Still it keep asking for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add this line in you LinearLayout: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: It gave me same error.

Comment: Can you share your XML file?

Answer (score 1):

`"xmlns:android"` You have this line added twice in your code in `LinearLayout`. Also, Try `Invalidate & Cache Restart` and then run the code.

Comment: same result bro